# how to copy matching number or non matching number in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do i find matching or non matching numbers between two sheets and copy the matching numbers into sheet3 column A and B for non matching numbers. here is my code but some how it's not working.

```
      For i = 1 To lastrow
         For ii = 1 To xlastrow
              If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i,1) = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(ii, 1) Then
                   Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A" & x) = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1)                  
                    x = x + 1
              ElseIf Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i,1) <> Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(ii, 1) Then
                   Worksheets("sheet3").Range("B" & x) = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1)                  
                    x = x + 1

         Next ii
       Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised that excel is not responding.

If I understand correctly, you're running a nested loop with 4000 to 5000 iterations each, so up to 25,000,000 iterations all up, during which you reference multiple spreadsheet cell values.

It is likely that whatever you are trying to do (which is not entirely clear) could be done better with worksheet functions like vlookup.

If you must use nested loops, one thing you could do to speed it up a lot would be to read all the values into an array first and loop over this array rather than the spreadsheet cells directly.

Comment: I can't use vlookup, only vba and what im trying to do is finding matching or non matching numbers